# How can I prevent infinite loop in subprocess of python?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess

I am writing a python script that executes another program with bash command.

I am using `subprocess.Popen()` function for it. However in some conditions the external program gives me an error and tries to run same comment infinitely.

How can I catch that error and break `Popen` function.

Assume that program gives its error as an output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `poll()` or `communicate()` function for this.  These methods return [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) once the process terminates. The return code is `None` as long as programme is running.

You can try using below code

```
from subprocess import Popen

process = Popen('bash your_script.sh')

while process.poll() is None:
     print 'keep running'

process.terminate()
```